# Multi-Dimensional array from MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql

This is MySQL Query:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` , `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'zfk'
```

How can I make multi dimensional arrays:
Level 1 TABLE_SCHEMA  *(The above query is just a demo, else real query has no `where` clause).*
Level 2 TABLE_NAME
Level 3 COLUMN_NAME

MySQL Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'zfk'");

$resulting_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)){
    $resulting_array[] = $row;
}

print_r($resulting_array);
```

This will print out:

```
[0] => array([0] => zfk, [1] => zfk_clients, [2] => id
[1] => array([0] => zfk, [1] => zfk_clients, [2] => company_name
[2] => array([0] => zfk, [1] => zfk_clients, [2] => web_address
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=information_schema", "XXXX", "XXXX");
$sql = "SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` , `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME`
        FROM `COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'zfk'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$zfk = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $s = $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"];
  $t = $row["TABLE_NAME"];
  $c = $row["COLUMN_NAME"];
  $zfk[$s][$t][$c] = 1;
}
print_r($zfk);
```

It outputs a three-dimensional array with schema names as the first dimension, table names as the second dimension, and column names as the third dimension.

Comment: Of course I don't have a schema named `zfk` so I used my `test` schema.